# Narrow label space on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating form with label and input.
My lable have two words and it going on 2 lines.

in which class should i use to coreect it???

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">'User name'</label>

        <div class="col-sm-push-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind='value: businessName'>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, use `col-sm-2`, if that also don't fix it, try try the next.

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">'User name'</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `form-inline`? You can put the label and the input in the same group

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">'User name'</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: businessName">        
  </div>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/120996